# Why can't I get more attributes from google provider via cognito UserInfo endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have configured google provider via cognito user pool and I am able to login through google and get user information. And I have added many attributes on the attribute mapping page as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

The endpoint I am using to get user info is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/userinfo-endpoint.html.

The response data for user info is always:

```
data: {
    identities: '[{"userId":"xxxx","providerName":"Google","providerType":"Google","issuer":null,"primary":true,"dateCreated":1587772412295}]',
    email_verified: 'true',
    email: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    username: 'Google_1xxxx'
  }
```

Regardless how I update the attribute mappings, I always see above response. Why can't I get additional attributes like `picture`, `given_name`, `birthday` etc. Do I need to set any permission on google side?

In app client setting, I have below configuration:

[image]

In authorized scope, I have set: `email openid profile`

Comment: I'm curious if you ever solved this. I'm having the same issue. I use CF to deploy and one difference I have is I specify Google specific scopes that are not available in the console (ie, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read). Doing so causes the user to be asked for permission to read the birthday. However, I am still unable to successfully map birthday to either a standard or custom attribute.