# Missing userAttributes for federated Google User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, google-authentication

I'm trying to integrate Google as an IdP in our existing Cognito UserPool. Everything is set up so far, and I can SignUp/SignIn using Google, which creates the new user. I'm using the PreSignUp Lambda trigger to Link an existing user or create a new native one if there's no existing one. Now I was expecting that the `event.Request.UserAttributes['name']` contains the user's name as provided by Google or at least seeing the attribute in the `id_token`. But I see no possibility to get those values at the moment. We started using Cognito just as the store for username/password, and none of the userAttributes are filled nor marked as required.

I have set up the Google integration with the following scopes:

- `.../auth/userinfo.email`
- `.../auth/userinfo.profile`
- `openid`

In the UserPoolClient I:

- marked `name` as read- and writeable attribute (along with others)
- Checked the following allowed OAuth scopes `email`, `openid`, and `profile`. Those are also defined in the Web-Client in charge of the OAuth flow.

In the Federation section, I configured the attribute mapping:
[image: Attribute mapping for Google in Cognito]

Testwise, I mapped the `name` attribute to a custom attribute I used to test stuff. But neither this nor the mapping `name` to `name` worked.

Payload I get in the event:

```
{{PreSignUp_ExternalProvider .... Google_11...} {map[cognito:email_alias: cognito:phone_number_alias: email:m...@...m email_verified:true] map[] map[]} {false false false}}
```

`id_token` content:

```
{
  "at_hash": "..",
  "sub": "52...",
  "email_verified": true,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/...",
  "cognito:username": "52..",
  "origin_jti": "..",
  "aud": "...",
  "identities": [
    {
      "userId": "11...",
      "providerName": "Google",
      "providerType": "Google",
      "issuer": null,
      "primary": "false",
      "dateCreated": "1648828708886"
    }
  ],
  "token_use": "id",
  "auth_time": 1648828717,
  "exp": 1648830828,
  "iat": 1648830228,
  "jti": "...",
  "email": "m...@...m"
}
```

`access_token` content:

```
{
  "origin_jti": "02...",
  "sub": "52...",
  "token_use": "access",
  "scope": "openid profile",
  "auth_time": 1648828717,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/....",
  "exp": 1648829317,
  "iat": 1648828717,
  "version": 2,
  "jti": "..",
  "client_id": "...",
  "username": "52..."
}
```

Comment: Probably some similarities with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61435551/why-cant-i-get-more-attributes-from-google-provider-via-cognito-userinfo-endpoi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's working, even though I cannot state the error. I  recreated the whole test set again and ensured the correct values of the following:

- attribute mappings
- authorized scopes
- Allowed OAuth scopes
- Scopes selected by the frontend

I added the scopes `email`, `profile`, and `openid` to be sure, and now I get the `name` attribute within the pre signup trigger lambda and in the ID-Token.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using cognito as an authorizer for a REST API Gateway setup as a lambda proxy. In my case, the claims that the lambda received did not include all the user's attributes for a user signed in with Google.

Finally I identified that the issue was in the front-end configuration for getting the id tokens from cognito. I was using Amplify Auth and was missing the `'profile'` scope in the oauth configuration.

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        ...
        oauth: {
            ...
            scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
            ...
        }
    }
});
```